# How to check against a time value?

Tags: python, django, time

I would like to know if the given time is in the morning or afternoon.  I am not sure if this the correct way to create Time objects in python and do comparison against. Or is there a better way?

```
def part_of_day_statistics(x):
    if x > time.strptime('6:00 am') and x < time.strptime('11:59 am'):
        return 'Morning' 
    if x > time.strptime('12:00 pm') and x < time.strptime('5:59 pm'):
        return 'Afternoon'
```

Comment: Presumably `x` is a unix timestamp (seconds since the epoch)?

Comment: Sorry, no it is a time field in Django `contact_time = models.TimeField()`

Comment: Ah, that's a `datetime.time` field..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django [`TimeField` entries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#timefield) are [`datetime.time` instances](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#time-objects), which have an `.hour` attribute (ranging from 0 to 23):

```
def part_of_day_statistics(x):
    if x.hour >= 6 and x.hour < 12:
        return 'Morning'
    if x.hour >= 12 and x.hour < 18:
        return 'Afternoon'
```

Comment: Fantastic. That was far simpler than I thought. :) Thank you